# How to get a 3D picture in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, 3d, cocos2d-iphone

In an application, i saw that they used to display pictures of vehicles. But what was amazing was when we touch and swipe in that picture, it rotates in 3d way left and right. And from the front view we can rotate and get to see its back view also. It is a very good feature and i was trying to replicate it. But couldnt get an idea of how and where to start. My doubts are

1. Whats the actual format of the thing, it surely isn't a picture.
2. How do they get to rotate it?

Could someone give me an idea where i should start or where I should look upon?

Comment: 3D stuff should be done using 3D frameworks (OpenGLES) not 2D ones (cocos2d).

Comment: So any idea how to do it? Should we take all the pictures(left and right) of that certain object to achieve that effect?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413919/want-to-display-a-3d-model-on-the-iphone-how-to-get-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the KennyTM told you, OpenGL-ES is the weapon of choice. Take pictures of that object from all the sides you need to show, then use those as textures for the faces of the cube. Got the idea?

Comment: now having a relook at the application, i think its what they also have done. Thanks for the idea.