# Is there an tutorial on loading an 3D model in openGL ES on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es

I've started to play around with some 3d modelers a while ago. Now I'm curious: How can I bring such an 3D model to the iPhone or iPad, so that I can see it on screen and maybe even rotate it with gestures?

1) What's the best file format for the 3D models?

2) How would I load a particular 3D model file into openGL ES and then render it?

3) How would I apply an material to the polys, i.e. to make the model appear red?

4) Does the model have some sort of center or pivot point where I can rotate it easily around? Or do I need incredible freakin' math skills to transform all the vertecies in 3D space myself? How hard is it to rotate something?

5) Can I scale models or fit them into the camera viewport? How hard is that to do? Freakin' awesome math skills needed?

5) Does openGL ES support some kind of shader tree model with gradients and effects that can be applied to the model or material?

Would be so happy if someone can point out an quick starting guide for people who know 3D, but don't know OpenGL ES. Maybe someone already made a great tutorial on this topic?

Comment: While it doesn't entirely answer all of your questions (which might be better if broken out individually), you might want to look at the question [Want to display a 3D model on the iPhone: how to get started?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413919/want-to-display-a-3d-model-on-the-iphone-how-to-get-started)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [Using 3D Models from Blender in OpenGL ES](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-3d-models-from-blender-in-opengl.html).

Comment: +1 Using blender is my favorite way of generating content for OpenGL (ES) projects.

Comment: Does anyone have a backup of that script mentioned in the article?  The site Jeff Lamarche links to for all his resources appears to be broken / down / doesn't resolve its DNS