# Looking for an example application, including source code, that displays blender created 3d graphics on the iphone

Tags: iphone, 3d, blender

Is there a documented example that shows the process of taking 3D models and animations created on blender, and displaying them as part of an iPhone/iPad application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[want to display a 3d model on iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914632/is-there-an-tutorial-on-loading-an-3d-model-in-opengl-es-on-the-iphone)
please go through the link provided above