# best iphone 3d game engine

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, 3d, game-engine

which is the best iphone 3d game engine,

i already know cocos2d, in cocos3d , i dont know how to make basic samples,

at the same time am researching any other 3d game engines is better than cocos3d.

if you guys suggest any engines,  give link or sample for learn that faster......

game engines supports objective c as main like cocos2d

Comment: I think Unity3D is very popular for iPhone game development. To get a better feeling for your options, there are 37 iPhone game engines listed here: [iPhone Game engines](http://mobilegameengines.com/iphone/game_engines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using Ogre3D, it's free under MIT license, it's super fast and easy to learn :)
http://www.ogre3d.org/

Comment: not really. Apple is at war with C++, and each new xcode version is a giant waste of time each time I want to have a working project file.

Comment: This is an old one :) right now I would definitely go with Unity as a choice.

Comment: yeah right, good luck tuning that unity monster without paying them.

Comment: @jokoon why is that? Unity free can be used for everyone who profits less than $100K a year.

Answer (score 8):

The term best calls for personalized opinions which is not what stackoverflow likes.

But I am familiar (sort of) with Cocos3D and it is a great framework.

1. It is free and open source.
2. You can use other 3D modeling tools like Blender, Maya etc to create
   models, and you can export these models to iOS. I have written an
   answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413919/want-to-display-a-3d-model-on-the-iphone-how-to-get-started/18053562#18053562) to export Blender models to iOS.
3. It does have support for 2D physics engine like Box2D.
4. You can integrate Bullet 3D physics engine if you want 3D engine.
5. Most importantly, it is a super set of popular free open source 2D
   game engine Cocos2D, so you can use Cocos2d features in your
   project.

Comment: i dont know who will put down vote, now only am seeing your cooments

Comment: Just putting some plain links in can be done via comments, at least put descriptions in for your links in if you post an answer.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche was new to SO then. Edited the answer :)

Comment: I see, cheers for following up here.

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

Unreal
http://www.udk.com/mobile

Unity 3D
http://unity3d.com/unity/

Comment: I personally think unity also.

Answer (score 0):

the best one I know -

http://unity3d.com/