# How to use 3D models in Xcode (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, model, 3d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Want to display a 3D model on the iPhone: how to get started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413919/want-to-display-a-3d-model-on-the-iphone-how-to-get-started)

First let me say that if this has already been answered somewhere I'm very sorry - this is proving to be a bit complicated. My associate and I are working on an iPhone app, he's using xcode on a Mac but he's coming from a C++ background and is still learning Obj-C, and I am working on the art assets on a Windows PC.
We have yet to figure out what I can export my animated models to that xcode will allow us to import.

Comment: Check this out as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413919/want-to-display-a-3d-model-on-the-iphone-how-to-get-started

Comment: Xcode is merely an IDE for developing applications.  It doesn't have any particular support for 3-D models beyond what you've coded in your application.  As Luke points out, you can refer to many other questions here on Stack Overflow for how to write code (or use an engine) to display these models, but Xcode doesn't really have anything to do with that.

Comment: What about Unity3D? So you can use C# and they allow you to import models in different formats like Blender, Maya, ...