# How to export to Collada form in Blender for cocos3d

Tags: blender, collada, cocos3d

I am using blender 2.66a to create 3dobject for Cocos3d. In THE BRENWILL tutorial they have used blender 2.4.9 to export to collada file. I cannot find those options that have mentioned in the tutorial(like Triangle,only export selection), when export to collada file.

Where can i find those options in blender 2.66 ? Or is there any difference in options for higher version?

As pod file collada-pod file creation is very important in cocos3d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In blender 2.4.9 we have to specify the options to create collada file. But in blender 2.66 you can create collada file by using the default options. Then convert it into pod file using PowerVR SDK.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to existing answer, you can directly export your 3D models from blender to **.POD** format that cocos3d understands. For accomplishing this, you need to add a PowerVR SDK add-on to blender.

Steps to add PVRGeoPOD add-on to blender are

1. Download the PowerVR SDK(which you may have already done) from
   [this](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp) site. Note that this downloads an installer file, which in
   turns downloads the SDK. During the installation process, they ask
   you to select what tools need to be installed, I normally select

   - PVRGeoPOD
   - PVRShaman (optional, but highly recommended)

   options. First one is the **.blend** to **.POD** (and **COLLADA** to
   **.POD**) converter (including add-ons) and second one is a very useful **.POD** file viewer. Wait till the installation is complete.
2. Find the Blender add-on path. If you don't know it by heart,  open
   Blender python console, and run command
   `bpy.utils.script_paths("addons")` and note down the path.
3. Find the Blender add-on files inside the PVRGeoPOD folder, in your
   installation path. When you see files like **libPVRGeoPOD.dylib**
   and **PVRGeoPODScript.py** and 2 QT files, stop there because these
   are the add-on files. Copy these 4 files and paste them in Blender
   add-on folder.
4. Open Blender, run **Preference->add-ons tab**, search for
   **PVRGeoPOD**. You can see, that the add-on is there, but it is not enabled. Check the tick mart to the right to enable it.
5. Now Quit and restart Blender, if needed, and select **file->export**
   and see if there is an option called **PVRGeoPOD(.pod/.h/.cpp)**, if
   yes,you are successful. Now you can export directly from **.blend**
   to **.POD**

You can find a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18053562/640731).